# ios_command: Connection type ssh is not valid for this module

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Ansible `raw` command can work via SSH, but this playbook cannot work with the same Cisco command `show version`.

It is giving this error message, related to SSH:

> fatal: [192.168.1.15]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connection type ssh is not valid for this module"}

Here is the inventory under *inventory/host-file*

```
[routers]
192.168.1.15
[routers:vars]

ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_user=admin
ansible_password=admin
ansible_connection=network_cli
```

And the playbook *playbooks/show_version.yml*

```yaml
---
    
- name: Cisco show version example
  hosts: routers
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: run show version on the routers
      ios_command:
        commands: show version | incl Version
      register: output

    - name: print output
      debug:
        var: output.stdout_lines
```

Here is my file structure

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── inventory
│   └── host-file
└── playbooks
    └── show_version.yml
```

I do run the playbook with the command below, from the folder *playbooks*

```sh
ansible-playbook show_version.yml
```

Is this a SSH issue?
Can anyone share some experience?

Comment: _Is this ssh issue_ > Yes, as prompted in notes of the manual: _This module works with connection `network_cli`. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_ios.html_ https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_command_module.html#notes

Comment: Your real issue, though, seems to be that your are thinking that Ansible will automatically use a file inside the _inventory_ folder as your inventory. **This is not true**, unless you specified this in your _ansible.cfg_ file or you pass this file as `-i` option of your playbook.

Comment: But, as for your other recent questions, you are lacking to provide a [mre], and here, specifically, how is the inventory is supposedly used in your scenario.

Comment: I edited your question to show you a bit how to strucure a question correctly, instead of having a huge blob of console dump, so you can improve your future questions.

Comment: You also have to mind one important thing, about _ansible.cfg_, it is its location cannot be anywhere ([see in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file)) and since you are running this playbook from inside the _playbooks_ folder, the configuration file you are showing in your file structure is most likely not taken into consideration!

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thank you very much for your editing question and very good suggestion! it started to work now.

Answer (score 1):

According your error message

> `Connection type ssh is not valid for this module`

at least the variable `ansible_connection` wasn't set with a value as it should. A minimal working example from a running environment

```yaml
---
- name: Cisco show version example
  hosts: routers
  gather_facts: false

  vars: # for execution environment
  
    ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
    ansible_network_os: cisco.ios.ios
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_method: enable

  tasks:

  - name: Gather only the config and default facts
    cisco.ios.ios_facts:
      gather_subset:
      - config

  - name: Show facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.net_version }}"
```

In respect to the given comments, maybe you can add a debug task in your playbook

```yaml
- name: Show 'ansible_*' values
  debug:
    msg: 
      - "{{ ansible_network_os }}"
      - "{{ ansible_connection }}"

- meta: end_play
```

to see what gets actually loaded.