# "module_stderr": "Shared connection to <IP> closed.\r\n" when connecting to Cisco Switch

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Hi all I have been trying to connect my Ansible Control Node to Cisco Switch.

I am able to ping/ssh but when it comes to Ansible, it just fails.

I am getting this error below when I use the ad-hoc command

```bash
ansible cisco_node -m ping
```

```json
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [11.11.11.203]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [11.11.11.203]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
cisco_node | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 11.11.11.203 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 0
}
```

```bash
ansible version: core 2.15.4
which python:/usr/bin/python
```

I tried to point to `/usr/bin/python3` it is still hitting the same error.

Appreciate your help and advise. Thanks in advance.

Hope that I can get to connect to my Cisco Switch for some testing by using `ansible-playbook`.

Answer (score 0):

According the information provided it seems that you try to establish a SSH connection to a switch. Such devices may not have all capabilities for Python scripts.

Because of [`ping` module – Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html) it

- "*is NOT ICMP ping, ... just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node*"
- is a "*... test module, this module always returns pong on successful contact. It does not make sense in playbooks, but it is useful from /usr/bin/ansible to verify the ability to login and that a usable Python is configured.*"

In order to establish a connection to your not further specified Cisco Switch you may read first about

- [IOS Platform Options](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_ios.html)
- [Ansible Network Collection for Cisco IOS devices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/index.html)

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: 'ping' <NetworkDevice> results into error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73955446/6771046)
- [`ios_command`: Connection type ssh is not valid for this module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71022995/6771046)
- [How to connect to Cisco NX-OS switch using Ansible in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76399274/6771046)

Comment: Hi I tried to use the playbook below but it still getting the same error:

---
- name: Connect to cisco node
  hosts: cisco_node
  tasks:
    - name: Run uptime command
      command: show version
      register: result

    - name: Display command output
      debug:
        var: result.stdout_lines

Comment: It is recommended to update your initial question with all necessary new information and error messages by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to my `/etc/ansible/hosts`:

```
ansible_connection=network_cli ansible_network_os=ios
```

It seems to be working already.